# Reading SMS's on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, mobile

I've seen that it is not possible to read SMS's on iOS, (unless the phone is jailbroken) but there has been no recent answers to this question. Does anyone know whether they have updated iOS to actually allow for the reading of SMS's?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If it's related to iPhones, try posting it on https://apple.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

Still not possible.

If you want more reference, someone asked this at Apple forums:

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/93860

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/16685

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, appreciate the references.